# change specific word color in wordcloud

Tags: r, word-cloud

I would like to build a word cloud with R (I have done so with the package **wordcloud**) and then color specific words a certain color.  Currently the behavior of the function is to color words according to frequency (which can be useful) but word size already does this so I'd want to use color for additional meaning.

Any idea on how to color specific words in wordcloud?  (If there's another wordcloud function in R I'm unaware of I'm more than willing to go that route.)

A mock example and my attempt (I tried to treat the color argument in the same manor I would a regular plot from the plot function):

```
library(wordcloud)

x <- paste(rep("how do keep the two words as one chunk in the word cloud", 3), 
           collapse = " ")
X <- data.frame(table(strsplit(x, " ")))
COL <- ifelse(X$Var1 %in% c("word", "cloud", "words"), "red", "black")
wordcloud(X$Var1, X$Freq, color=COL)
```

*EDIT:  I wanted to add that the new version of wordcloud (Jan 10, 2010; version 2.0)[Thank you Ian Fellows & David Robinson] now was this feature along with some other terrific additions.
Here is the code to accomplish the original goal within wordcloud:*

```
wordcloud(X$Var1, X$Freq, color=COL, ordered.colors=TRUE, random.color=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: As described in the comments, the feature described below has now been added to the [wordcloud](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/index.html) library.

---

My approach was to take the R function's code and customize it. It required changing only a few lines, and can now take either a single color or a vector of colors of the same length as `words`.

```
library(wordcloud)

colored.wordcloud <- function(words,freq,scale=c(4,.5),min.freq=3,max.words=Inf,random.order=TRUE,random.color=FALSE,
        rot.per=.1,colors="black",ordered.colors=FALSE,use.r.layout=FALSE,...) { 
    tails <- "g|j|p|q|y"
    last <- 1
    nc<- length(colors)

    if (ordered.colors) {
        if (length(colors) != 1 && length(colors) != length(words)) {
            stop(paste("Length of colors does not match length of words",
                       "vector"))
        }
    }

    overlap <- function(x1, y1, sw1, sh1) {
        if(!use.r.layout)
            return(.overlap(x1,y1,sw1,sh1,boxes))
        s <- 0
        if (length(boxes) == 0) 
            return(FALSE)
        for (i in c(last,1:length(boxes))) {
            bnds <- boxes[[i]]
            x2 <- bnds[1]
            y2 <- bnds[2]
            sw2 <- bnds[3]
            sh2 <- bnds[4]
            if (x1 < x2) 
                overlap <- x1 + sw1 > x2-s
            else 
                overlap <- x2 + sw2 > x1-s

            if (y1 < y2) 
                overlap <- overlap && (y1 + sh1 > y2-s)
            else 
                overlap <- overlap && (y2 + sh2 > y1-s)
            if(overlap){
                last <<- i
                return(TRUE)
            }
        }
        FALSE
    }

    ord <- rank(-freq, ties.method = "random")
    words <- words[ord<=max.words]
    freq <- freq[ord<=max.words]
    if (ordered.colors) {
        colors <- colors[ord<=max.words]
    }

    if(random.order)
        ord <- sample.int(length(words))
    else
        ord <- order(freq,decreasing=TRUE)
    words <- words[ord]
    freq <- freq[ord]
    words <- words[freq>=min.freq]
    freq <- freq[freq>=min.freq]
    if (ordered.colors) {
        colors <- colors[ord][freq>=min.freq]
    }

    thetaStep <- .1
    rStep <- .05
    plot.new()
    op <- par("mar")
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
    plot.window(c(0,1),c(0,1),asp=1)
    normedFreq <- freq/max(freq)
    size <- (scale[1]-scale[2])*normedFreq + scale[2]
    boxes <- list()



    for(i in 1:length(words)){
        rotWord <- runif(1)<rot.per
        r <-0
        theta <- runif(1,0,2*pi)
        x1<-.5
        y1<-.5
        wid <- strwidth(words[i],cex=size[i],...)
        ht <- strheight(words[i],cex=size[i],...)
        #mind your ps and qs
        if(grepl(tails,words[i]))
            ht <- ht + ht*.2
        if(rotWord){
            tmp <- ht
            ht <- wid
            wid <- tmp  
        }
        isOverlaped <- TRUE
        while(isOverlaped){
            if(!overlap(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,wid,ht) &&
                    x1-.5*wid>0 && y1-.5*ht>0 &&
                    x1+.5*wid<1 && y1+.5*ht<1){
        if (!random.color) {
                if (ordered.colors) {
                    cc <- colors[i]
                }
                else {
                    cc <- ceiling(nc*normedFreq[i])
                    cc <- colors[cc]
                }
        } else {
         cc <- colors[sample(1:nc,1)]
        }
                text(x1,y1,words[i],cex=size[i],offset=0,srt=rotWord*90,
                        col=cc,...)
                #rect(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,x1+.5*wid,y1+.5*ht)
                boxes[[length(boxes)+1]] <- c(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,wid,ht)
                isOverlaped <- FALSE
            }else{
                if(r>sqrt(.5)){
                    warning(paste(words[i],
                                    "could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted."))
                    isOverlaped <- FALSE
                }
                theta <- theta+thetaStep
                r <- r + rStep*thetaStep/(2*pi)
                x1 <- .5+r*cos(theta)
                y1 <- .5+r*sin(theta)
            }
        }
    }
    par(mar=op)
    invisible()
}
```

Some code to try it out:

```
colors = c("blue", "red", "orange", "green")
colored.wordcloud(colors, c(10, 5, 3, 9), colors=colors)
```

Comment: Perfect.  I would like to include this in an open source package.  I want to appropriately cite this and make sure you're ok with including it (I assume Ian Fellows will need to be asked as well).

Comment: Ian Fellows has probably already given you permission to use it in a package under the terms of his license. If it's a typucal GNU license it would require that you also require that future users to keep it open-source.

Comment: By all means, include away. One disclaimer I should note is that I had to get rid of the option to use the C++ layout for this to work- it always uses the R layout. (That is, I commented out the "if (!use.r.layout)" lines- perhaps someone else can get them to work)

Comment: Of course. wordcloud is distributed under lgpl. Your other option is to submit a patch to me adding the additional functionality.

Comment: Done: emailed a proposed patch to Ian (not sure if there's a system I should use for such submissions). Included a couple of adjustments now reflected in above code.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks david :) Does the proposal include the ability to use the user defined colors with the C++ layout?

Comment: Yes, that was just a simple issue with accessing the .overlap function from the new R code, which is not an issue when the package itself is changing. Like I said, a more experienced user might be able to get it to work anyway.

Comment: @David Robinson Thanks for that initiative.  I think this is a terrific addition and hopefully Ian accepts the proposal.  This is a nice feature that would extend my discourse analysis package but a colored wordcloud function really doesn't fit with the rest of my package, so I'm hoping this is the route Ian takes.  Thank you for your work.

Comment: New version of [wordcloud](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/index.html), just released, now includes this feature (along with [some other cool features](http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=101)). 36 hours from @TylerRinker's original question- not bad, team!