# How to set spacing between words in wordcloud?

Tags: r, word-cloud

When I run

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)
set.seed(2)

wordcloud(
  words = c("One", "Two", "Three"),
  freq = c(100, 50, 20)
)
```

I get a plot looking like

[image]

How can I adjust the spacing between words?

I tried:

1. to increase the size of the plot first by increasing the size of the *Plots* window in *RStudio*, this did not help.
2. to increase the size of the plot by plotting it via `png()` and increasing the file size with setting `width` and `height`, this did not help neither.

Also playing around with different values of `scale` does not help.

The only workaround I found is to run the code and to increase the height of the *Plots* window in *RStudio* **after** the wordcloud has been plotted. ..but this cannot be the solution..

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335444/r-wordcloud-package-what-do-the-values-in-scale-represent) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781700/change-specific-word-color-in-wordcloud) help?

Comment: @Christoph The first link: No, not really. The `scale` parameter does something different... The second link: Maybe, if changing the function is the solution. I still hope for some tweak that does not involve redefining the `wordcloud` function itself.